# erase() in list does not work in c++ on MacOS. What is bash: line 1: 88225 Segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, erase

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    list<int> mylist;
    list<int>::iterator it;

    for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
        mylist.push_back(i);
    }
    for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout<<endl;

    for(it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end();it++){
        if((*it)==2){
            mylist.erase(it);
            mylist.insert(it,9);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that mylist.erase(it) is not working because when I delete it, the program works.

The output for the above program is

> 1 2 3 4 5
> bash: line 1: 88370 Segmentation fault: 11  "/Users/alimtleuliyev/Desktop/quiadratic"
> [Finished in 441ms with exit code 139]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write

```
   if((*it)==2){
        it = mylist.erase(it);
        mylist.insert(it,9);
        break;
    }
```

To output the list it is better to use the range-based for loop.

Also to find an element in the list with the given value it is better to use the standard algorithm `std::find` instead of using a for loop.

Here is  a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;

    for ( int i = 1; i < 6; i++ ) 
    {
        mylist.push_back( i );
    }

    for (const auto &item : mylist)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto it = std::find( std::begin( mylist ), std::end( mylist ), 2 );

    if ( it != std::end( mylist) )
    {
        it = mylist.erase( it );
        mylist.insert( it, 9 );
    }

    for (const auto &item : mylist)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 9 3 4 5
```

Pay attention to that instead of calling the member functions `erase` and `insert` you could just write

```
    if ( it != std::end( mylist) ) *it = 9;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. However, I was wondering why in some cases it works for other people? Like they do not assign the function to iterator. For example, [Look first example here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-erase-function-in-c-stl/)

Comment: @AlimTleuliyev You need to use a valid iterator in the call of insert. After calling erase the iterator it becomes invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much man. Seems like I still don’t know a lot of things. For example. I did not know about the range-based. This (const auto &item : mylist) is unfamiliar to me. Where can I learn this?

Comment: One more question - why do you need to check if iterator is not at the end of list?

Comment: @AlimTleuliyev If the returned iterator is equal to the mylist.end() then it means that an element with teh value 2 is not found.

Comment: @AlimTleuliyev see [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) on cppreference.com